# distributed algorithms simulation in erlang

Tags: algorithm, erlang, distributed

I'm a beginner with Erlang.  I would like to use it to observe the execution of "textbooks" distributed algorithm (leader election, consensus...)for pedagogic purpose. At that stage, I describe the topology of my system as a graph (dict from int to list of ints) and based on that, i instanciate and initialize my nodes with a list of their neighbors. It works fine but it seems a bit ad-hoc. There must be a more generic way of doing this. Common libraries or tools that could help?

If not, do you think what I'm doing make sense? see below.

```
-module(control).
-export([init/1, init/4]).

% create N processes 1 .. N and return a dict from
% 1..N to Pids
create(_, 0, Dict) -> Dict ;
create(Module, N, Dict) ->
  Id = spawn(Module, proc, [nil]),
  Id ! init_state,
  create(Module, N-1, dict:append(N, Id, Dict)).

% broadcast a Signal to all processes in Dict
broadcast(Dict, Signal) ->
  F = fun (_, [Y]) -> Y ! Signal end,
  dict : map (F, Dict),
  ok. 

% send a Signal to process Dict(I)
send(Dict, I, Signal) ->
  [Id] = dict : fetch(I, Dict),
  Id ! Signal,
  ok.

% wait for N ok signals
syncr(0) -> ok;
syncr(N) ->
  receive 
    ok -> io : format("ok received ~n", []), syncr(N-1) 
  end.

% init neighbors according to topology Graph
init_topology(Dict, Graph) ->
  F = fun(X) -> [Res] = dict : fetch(X, Dict), Res end,
  IdToPId = fun(L) -> lists : map(F, L) end,
  G = fun (I, [Y]) -> 
      [LId] = dict : fetch(I, Graph),
      LPId = IdToPId(LId),
      Y ! {neighbors, LPId, self()} end,
  dict : map (G, Dict),
  ok. 

% init all states with unary function Signal : I -> term.
init_state(Dict, Signal) ->
  F = fun (I, [Y]) -> Y ! {init, Signal(I), self()} end,
  dict : map (F, Dict),
  ok. 

% init all process according to the given topology and Signal : I -> term
% returns a pair of function Send and Broadcast
init(Module, N, Graph, Signal) ->
  Dict = create(Module, N, dict:new()),
  init_topology(Dict, Graph),
  init_state(Dict, Signal),
  syncr(2 * N),
  Send = fun (I, S) -> send(Dict, I, S) end,
  Broadcast = fun (S) -> broadcast(Dict, S) end,
  { Send, Broadcast }.

% this is a particular instanciation of a consensus algorithm with 
% N nodes
% a complete graph topology
% some initialisation of the process states
% the S and B returned functions allows me to interact with the system
% to start the algorithm for instance
init(N) -> {S, B} = control : init(consensus, N, topology : complete(N), fun(_)
      -> random : uniform(1000) end), {S,B}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTP has some rote ways of handling the above tasks. I say "rote" and not "generic" because they are OTP conventions and not universally accepted solutions to generic distributed algorithm implementation.

Things like initializing a graph of processes, messaging them, termination, synchronous signaling, etc. are the sort of things that OTP provides solutions to within the `application`/`supervisor`/`gen_`* concept. Maintaining a registry of processes can be handled by the `global` module, utilities like `gproc` or using process groups -- but the way you are handling process groups it seems more likely that a list of PIDs is a better fit than a process registry, or even your current process dictionary (the integer label assigned to a given process is meaningless, and it is unlikely you need to send a message to a specific process N without it having initiated the message chain itself, in which case you can already know its PID).

In any case, the OTP way of starting up a graph of processes is most useful when you are trying to solve an actual real-world problem, not a theoretical one. In theoretical systems nothing fails, code is perfect, and there are no users -- you are modeling an ideal case. In the real world things break, need to be monitored, bugs abound, people trip over electrical cords and network cables, and the common situation day-to-day is generally a mess. That real-world messiness is really what OTP is designed to help cope with, it only incidentally does so in a way that provides a rote method of declaring your program as a graph of processes -- the fact this is incidental is part of why the language of the "actor model" and distributed computing theory is not used much in the Erlang/OTP documentation.

A side effect of starting your system the OTP way is that monitoring, supervision, and some other practically useful (as in, "useful in a production environment where users depend on a system being available") things `application` gives you "just happen" without the need to add a bunch of code for monitoring, debugging, or ad hoc supervision strategies. But these are likely not the things you are really concerned with.

Something OTP *does not* provide is a generic set of consensus algorithm implementations. In most practical systems (and again, this is Erlang's real focus) a decision is made to cut the complexity of consensus down to a minimum and rely on arbitrary conditions to force adherence to a leadership model, even if that is temporarily destructive.

So on the one hand "Yes", Erlang/OTP provides rote methods to handle much of the code you wrote above, but on the other hand "No", Erlang/OTP was not designed with any particular theoretical model of distributed computing in mind and therefore its programming culture and its frameworks have made a conscious decision to place a higher priority on features that provide a shortcut to deployment of robust systems in production and a lower priority on implementation or adherence to theoretical foundations, so some functionality you might expect could be missing.

Comment: A good example of the the "practicality first" mindset of the Erlang community is illustrated in this ML thread about fault tolerance in the context of a distributed process registry: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-February/083194.html